# Nodejs Koa2: TyperError: ctx.render is not a function

Tags: node.js, koa2

I am pretty new to Node and Koa2, so please bear with me.

I am getting this error:

`TypeError: ctx.render is not a function`

This is the line where the error gets triggered:

```
class HtmlRouter {
    static async home(ctx) {
        await ctx.render('index.ejs', {});
    }
}
```

I am using `ejs` as the templating engine.

What am I doind wrong or missing?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just solved this by my own.

I had this:

```
app.use(body());

app.use(mount('/api/v1', filmRouter.routes()));
app.use(filmRouter.routes());
app.use(htmlRouter.routes());


app.use(views(__dirname + '/views', {
    map: {
        ejs: 'ejs'
    }
}));
```

The bug was due to the order of the middleware. In this order, it works fine:

```
app.use(body());

app.use(views(__dirname + '/views', {
    map: {
        ejs: 'ejs'
    }
}));


app.use(mount('/api/v1', filmRouter.routes()));
app.use(filmRouter.routes());
app.use(htmlRouter.routes());
```

Notice how in the former code snippet, the templating engine was being defined after the middleware that relies on it was being run.